# Cron not firing properly

Tags: cron

I have a cron job that is supposed to execute a bash script.  I have confirmed the bash script does work as the cron job works properly on my local machine.

However the cron job does not appear to be firing on a remote machine that I have access to.  As a test I am doing a touch command. My cron job is as follows:

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# 
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
# 
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').
# 
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# 
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# 
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# 
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command
21 12 * * * /usr/bin/touch /home/aidan/test.txt
```

This cron job should create a test.txt file in "/usr/bin/touch".  However, it appears that it is not firing at all.

To debug I have looked at "/var/log/syslog" using the following 2 commands:

1. sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep -w 'cron'
   In this command I am getting the following output:

```
Dec 13 20:21:01 onecup cron[1628]: (aidan) RELOAD (crontabs/aidan)
```

2. sudo grep CRON /var/log/syslog.
   In this command I am getting the following output:

```
Dec 13 17:17:01 onecup CRON[1060280]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec 13 18:17:01 onecup CRON[1120928]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec 13 19:17:01 onecup CRON[1180117]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec 13 20:17:01 onecup CRON[1238901]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Notice, that in this command the cron job does not appear at all.
My expectation is that the CMD should appear.

In short it appears the cronjob is reloading but **never** actually firing.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Also, note I did see this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60842683/cron-not-running-tasks-ubuntu-18-04.

It did not fix the issue.

Comment: @steeldriver I just double checked.  If I do: sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep -w 'CRON', I get:

Dec 13 22:17:01 onecup CRON[1372772]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)

So I don't even get any record of the job even reloading.

Comment: Oops sorry I didn't see you'd already checked both cases. Does the remote system have either of /etc/cron.allow or /etc/cron.deny files?

Comment: @steeldriver all good! It does not have either of /etc/cron.allow or /etc/cron.deny files

Comment: ... it seems odd that there appear to be no `cron.hourly` log entries around your crontab entry's 12:21 timespec (no `Dec 13 12:17:01` or `Dec 13 13:17:01` for example)

Comment: The log will usually say this but have you tried putting a new line after the command and then seeing if it runs.

Comment: The job is scheduled to run at 12:21.  Has that time happened yet?  All the timestamps that you are showing are in the evening.

Comment: For testing purposes, I normally have a separate terminal open, dedicated to setting a just-in-time event for each test. Waiting 24 hours between test shots ? My crontab has (commented-out) history like `*/3 * * * * cd /home/paul && ./Often 161 20 >> Often.log 2>&1`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue: The machine is operating in the UTC zone, and I'm in the PST zone.  So the cron job did not execute at the expected local time.